# CSS-only multi-columns with divs

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I'm currently working on a kind of server-interface. The user should be able to drag and drop its items to align the interface after his wishes. The easiest way would (and the way, I'd like it to work) would be, like in the Windows 8 start-menu, where you drag your blocks and the rest aligns itself.

I found the corresponding css-attribute, `(-preamble-)column-count`. This kind of works, but only for text. My widgets are `<div>`-containers.

So here are my questions:

1. Is there a possibility to allow only 3 rows and n columns?
2. How can you make the column-width stay the size (currently, it resizes with the viewport-size, even with the `-webkit-column-size` [Chrome 28]). This would bring up e.g. 3 items in one row.
3. How can I prevent huge gaps between the columns? `-webkit-column-gap` won't really change the gap, it only sets it minimum value. Setting the parent-container's width is not really an option, because I would really like to make it quite dynamic.

So, here's an example of what I'm trying to get, but wont work:

```
Before drag: 
1 | 2 | 7 | 8
3 | 4 | 9 | 10
5 | 6 | 11| 12

After dragging "5" behind "7"
1 | 2 | 5 | 8
3 | 4 | 9 | 10
6 | 7 | 11| 12
```

Just to make sure: 
I didn't mention the dragging-part, because I already have a solution for this problem. my current problem is only the alignment of the table.

To give you some example, I created a jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/mine/WmkPR/

Comment: Ok, I just figured out, that I can set the `height` attribute to define the amount of rows, so just ignore #1 :)

Comment: If you read the spec column-size is working as intended: [describes the optimal column width. The actual column width may be wider (to fill the available space), or narrower (only if the available space is smaller than the specified column width).](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#column-width).

Comment: Ok, I see. Now got it working a bit more, but the column-gap is still a problem, but I guess, I won't be able to fix it without defining a fixed width.

Comment: Is the reason you're using the multi-column module because you want the items to fill from top to bottom, left to right?  Your example layout doesn't demonstrate this (it shows left to right, top to bottom).

Comment: I think, both (the code here and my fiddle) show the both (correct me, if I'm wrong). I want to have two columns and those two columns from left to right, but I guess, I didn't get, what you wanted to say. The way I showed in both sources is the way I would like it to behave.

Comment: @cimmanon are you using a non-webkit browser?  If you are using webkit, the columns only seem to show up when I expand the page so the elements are aligned in 2 rows and 4 columns.